# Доступ к конфигу Chrome из расширения

Tags: javascript, ssl, chrome-extension

Если у сайта проблемы с сертификатом, как правило, Chrome блокирует его открытие. При помощи линка "Перейти на сайт (не безопасно)" сайт более не блокируется.

Пишу расширение Crhome для корпоративных нужд, есть ресурс в интрасети. Запросы из расширения к нему падают с **ERR_SSL...**, однако, если выполнить предварительно действия, описанные выше, запросы ходят нормально.

Мой вопрос:
Как програмно, из расширения добавить ресурс в вайт-лист, аналог клика по линку "Перейти на сайт (не безопасно)"?

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что это можно сделать программно, т.к. в этом случае не было бы смысла что-то блокировать. Скорее всего Вам нужно установить сертификат сервера/ресурса на компьютеры в домене.